# reorder json object nested properties by key

Tags: json, sorting, object, key, nested-loops

```
{
  "color_group_01": {
    "blue_50": "#4080fb",
    "blue_40": "#6fa1fc",
    "blue_30": "#9dc2fd",
    "blue_20": "#cadefe",
    "blue_10": "#ebf4ff",
    "blue_100": "#011338",
    "blue_90": "#011d5f",
    "blue_80": "#022b8f",
    "blue_70": "#053fc4",
    "blue_60": "#165cfa"
  },
  "color_group_02": {
    "green_90": "#022d0d",
    "green_80": "#044317",
    "green_70": "#0e6027",
    "green_100": "#071908",
    "green_60": "#198038",
    "green_50": "#24a148",
    "green_40": "#42be65",
    "green_30": "#6fdc8c",
    "green_20": "#a7f0ba",
    "green_10": "#defbe6"
  }
}
```

I have a JSON file that is generated as above. It has 12 "color_group_" objects.

What I want to do is re order the properties within each group by key to go from 10-100. And also keep the "color_group_" in order 01-12. Resulting like below:

```
{
  "color_group_01": {
    "blue_10": "#ebf4ff",
    "blue_20": "#cadefe",
    "blue_30": "#9dc2fd",
    "blue_40": "#6fa1fc",
    "blue_50": "#4080fb",
    "blue_60": "#165cfa",
    "blue_70": "#053fc4",
    "blue_80": "#022b8f",
    "blue_90": "#011d5f",
    "blue_100": "#011338"
  },
  "color_group_02": {
    "green_10": "#defbe6",
    etc...
  }
}
```

I am struggling how to do this? Could some please help? No jQuery solutions please :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First you need to load your JSON into a javascript object using JSON.parse(). However your objects don't really know a sorting of their keys, instead you can extract the keys of your object and sort them accordingly

```
const keysArray = Object.keys(yourObject).sort((a, b) => /* your sort function here */);
```

Then you can loop through this keysArray, which is now all your keys sorted and access your object from there

```
keysArray.forEach(key => console.log(yourObject[key]));
```